# Passing model data to view in MVC 5

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am darned new to the world of MVC 5 .NET... I am trying to get my head around the Tree Control from Ignite UI.

I need to retrieve my data from my model and pass it to my view... However, I keep getting the following error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.String]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[DataViewer.Models.Viewer]'.

Here is my model:

```
namespace DataViewer.Models
{
    [Table("dbo.table")]
    public class Viewer
    {
        [Key, Column(Order=0)] public long id { get; set; }
        public int Revision { get; set; }
        public string GeoPSRType { get; set; }
        public string GeoName { get; set; } 
        public string L2Name { get; set; }  
        public string L3Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

etc.

And my Controller:

```
namespace DataViewer.Controllers
{
    public class ViewerController : Controller
    {
        private ViewerDBContext db = new ViewerDBContext();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var result = db.Items.Select(i => i.GeoName).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n);

            return View(result);
        }
    }
}
```

And my view:

```
@model IQueryable<DataViewer.Models.Viewer>

@using Infragistics.Web.Mvc

@(Html.Infragistics().Tree()
        .DataSource(Model)
        .Bindings(b =>
            b.TextKey("GeoName")
            .PrimaryKey("ID")
            .ValueKey("ID")
            .ChildDataProperty("L2PSRType")
            )
        )
        .DataSource(Model)
        .LoadOnDemand(true)
        .DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("tree-data-on-demand"))
        .DataBind()
        .Render()
)
```

I figured the issue was that I should be passing a strongly typed  return-type by using

```
IQueryable<Viewer> result = 
db.Items.Select(i => i.GeoName).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n);
```

but that throws a different error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 
'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.String]', 
but this dictionary requires a model item of type 
'System.Linq.IQueryable<DataViewer.Models.Viewer>.' 
An explicit conversion exists, are you missing a cast?
```

Is this relating to the fact that I'm pretty rusty on strongly typed syntax, or am I just being a total maroon (or is it a combination)?

P.S. Also, I have no doubt that the Infragistics().Tree() portion of the view is not correct, I am really more concerned about getting my data to my view (at this point). I just wanted to include all code I had...

Comment: You are telling the View to Accept a model of type `IQueryable<DataViewer.Models.Viewer>` but you are not passing that type to the view. Instead you are passing the results of a database query. You need to `return View(*modelClass*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the wrong type to your view.  Look at the type of model the view expects:

```
@model IQueryable<DataViewer.Models.Viewer>
```

A queryable collection of `Viewer` objects.  But look at what you're giving it:

```
db.Items.Select(i => i.GeoName).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n);
```

A collection of `GeoName` properties.  Is `GeoName` by any chance a `string`?  (The error implies that it is.)

If your model is expecting a collection of objects, you need to give it such a collection.  You can't just give it some strings and expect it to convert those strings into objects.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply (and hopefully patience)... Yes, GeoName is a string. It is a column on the db table... So what @declaration would I put at the start of the model? I am sending a collection of GeoNames, so would I change model IQueryable<DataViewer.Models.Viewer> to model IQueryable<DataViewer.Models.Viewer.GeoName>?

Comment: @mrwienerdog: You would change it to the type being sent, which according to the error message is `IQueryable<string>`.

Comment: @mrwienerdog: Note that this means all your model is going to have is a collection of strings.  So if anything on your model needs other properties from that object then it won't be able to get that property from a string.

Comment: Right... Gotcha. Then I would also need to change my model delaration to at model IQueryable<string> instead of at model IQueryable<DataViewer.Models.Viewer>, correct?

Comment: @mrwienerdog: If all the model needs is a queryable collection of strings, yes.  (In fact, if all the model needs is *any* collection of strings then you might even use `IEnumerable<string>` so that it doesn't *need* to be queryable.  Depends on if you plan on *querying* the collection or just *enumerating* the collection.  Just as with method arguments, it's best to only require the functionality needed.)

Comment: Hello again @David, was hoping you might be able to help me out a touch more... I am trying to use the returned strings to be the start of a Ignite UI treeview. However, I need a collection of objects for this, not just strings. You mentioned before that this is just that, a collection of strings. How do you formulate a linq query to facilitate this?

Comment: @mrwienerdog: Well, that's the whole point from my answer and this resulting discussion.  Your view was expecting a collection of `Viewer` objects, you were giving it a collection of strings.  You either need to give it a collection of `Viewer` objects or change it to expect a collection of strings.  You chose the latter.  If what you really needed was the former then choose the former instead.  Pass a collection of `Viewer` objects to the view.

Comment: Totally understand that... But (and I'm sorry to be annoying about this)... I am very new to this whole LINQ business (and .NET in general). How the heck would I query the db to get a list of objects that I could use as the starting point of a tree view?

Comment: @mrwienerdog: To elaborate further... You are selecting only one property from `Items` in your query, so of course all you're *getting* is one property.  If you want the whole object, omit the `Select` entirely and just use the list of objects.  To get your `Distinct` to still work, however, you'll need to use a custom equality comparer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049.aspx  (And in your `OrderBy` you'll need to specify the specific property to use for ordering.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the view is expecting different data than you're providing it with your controller.

Inside your view:

```
@model IQueryable<DataViewer.Models.Viewer>
```

means the view is expecting an IQueryable<> collection of Viewer's, but inside your controller:

```
// GET: /Viewer/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var result = db.Items.Select(i => i.GeoName).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n);

    return View(result);
}
```

You are passing a collection of strings.

You need to either return Viewer's, or change the model of the view.

Answer (score 1):

Change your Action Result to this...

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
                    //  var result = db.Items.Select(i => i.GeoName).Distinct().OrderBy(n => n);
         Viewer model = new Viewer();
         model = (from x in db.Items
                 select new Viewer
                 {
                   GeoPSRType = x.FieldName
                  }).Distinct().FirstOrDefault().OrderBy(x => x.SomeField);


        return View(model);
    }
```

There's probably some syntax errors in that query but this gives you a general understanding of what you need to pass into the View